# How to use tensorflow function recompute_grad in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras-layer

I'm trying to reduce the GPU memory cost of DenseNet. I found someone use `tf.contrib.layers.recompute_grad` to complete this work in tensorflow. I have a Keras model and I want to use `tf.contrib.layers.recompute_grad` in Keras. I tried to use a Keras custom layer to wrap it up.

```
class Back_Recompute(Layer):
def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, w_decay, **kwargs):
    super(Back_Recompute, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.n_filters = filters
    self.we_decay = w_decay
    self.ks = kernel_size

def call(self, ip):
    global brcount

    with tf.variable_scope('BR_{}'.format(brcount), use_resource=True):
        def _x(inner_ip):
             x = Conv2D(self.n_filters, self.ks, kernel_initializer='he_normal', padding='same', use_bias=False,
                        kernel_regularizer=l2(self.we_decay))(inner_ip)
            return x

        brcount = brcount + 1

        _x = tf.contrib.layers.recompute_grad(_x)
        return _x(ip)  

def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    return (input_shape[0], input_shape[1], input_shape[2], self.n_filters)
```

But weird problem is that my train code was stuck in `fit_generator` and cannot execute without error message. Then I thought that was probably because of Keras layer, so I have changed Keras layer `Conv2D` to `tf.layers.conv2d`. When I run the train code, I got a error message: AttributeError: 'Activation' object has no attribute 'outbound_nodes'. I don't know how to use `tf.contrib.layers.recompute_grad` in Keras. Does someone can help me?

Comment: Have you figured out a solution?

Comment: Has anyone figured out a solution?